# Date Format as 2019-06-17T9:45:04Z

Tags: php, date

How to get the date in a format

```
2019-06-17T9:45:04Z
```

in php?

I tried

```
date("Y-m-dTH:i:sZ")
```

it is returning

```
2019-02-03UTC09:23:560
```

Comment: So `T` and `Z` are just strings for you?

Comment: yes it is string

Comment: Okay then the answer below solves it for you :-)

Comment: Datetime::ISO8601

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z")
```

Output:

```
2019-02-01T13:34:29Z
```

Comment: Notice the backslash. These are called escape sequences, more on those http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php.